# Live tail of Windows log file

Tags: windows, powershell

I have several Windows servers that I want to monitor a log file on them live and when a new line added with specific string to run a command on Linux server.

In order to tail the Windows log file I'm using the following command:

```
Get-Content <file name> -Wait | Select-String -Pattern <some string>
```

The command prints, all lines that having the string and new lines having the string.

How can I show just new lines from the moment I run the command and not all lines on the files ?

Comment: Please change the tag to Windows or something Windows relevant. You should use tags for the platform/language you want answers in/need help with. You are looking for a Windows command here, not Linux command.

Answer (score 10):

I solved the issue by running the following command:

```
get-content <file> -wait -tail 1 | select-string -pattern "<string>"
```

but need to make sure first that running it from PS V. 4